Stopping criterion of mathematical programming problem
I am currently working on a project that involves recreating results from A fix-and-optimize heuristic for the Unrelated Parallel Machine Scheduling Problem. I do not understand a constraint in the second formulation proposed by the authors, which consists of a two-level problem:

A master problem, which assigns each job to a machine
A sequence problem, which optimizes the job queue for each machine, having the assignments fixed by the master problem

The master problem inserts cuts in the formulation at each iteration. Given the following quantities:

$h$ is the iteration
$i$ is the index of each machine
$j$ is the index of each job
$C_\max$ is the makespan of the problem, i.e. the quantity that has to be minimized
$C_\max^{hi}$ is the makespan of machine i, i.e. how much time is needed for finishing the job queue
$N_i^h$ is the set of all jobs in the queue of machine $i$
$y_{i,j}$ is a binary variable that is 1 if job j is assigned to machine i, 0 otherwise
$\theta_{i,j}^h$ is the sum of the execution time of job j on machine i and the maximum setup time for j and any other job in the queue of machine i

The form of the cuts is as follows:
$$ C_{\max} \geq C^{hi}_{\max} - \sum_{j \in N_i^h} (1- y_{i,j}) \theta_{i,j}^h \quad  \forall i \in M $$
I do not understand how this cut can reduce the solution space, allowing the master problem to generate different solutions in subsequent iterations.
Thank you in advance for your patience and consideration.

Your link is broken, but from your description I see what's going on.  The master problem recommends values for $y_{i,j}$ to minimize $C_\max$, but without full knowledge of the true makespan that will result from a given master solution.  The subproblem computes the true makespan for each iteration $h$ and machine $i$ and returns $C_\max^{hi}$.  If the $C_\max$ value from the master solution is equal to $\max_i C^{hi}_\max$, then you have found an optimal solution to the original problem.  Otherwise, you need to convey to the master problem that the solution yields a higher objective value than claimed.  Explicitly, you need to impose a Benders optimality cut that enforces the following logical proposition for each $i\in M$:
$$\left(\bigwedge_{j \in N_i^h} (y_{i,j} = 1)\right) \implies C_{\max} \geq C^{hi}_{\max}. \tag1\label1$$
That is, if machine $i$ is assigned the tasks recommended by the master solution in iteration $h$, then the makespan is at least $C^{hi}_{\max}$.
The linear constraint in your question linearizes \eqref{1}.  After adding this constraint to the master problem, the master solver will no longer claim a too-low $C_\max$ value for that master solution.
For more information, search for combinatorial Benders decomposition or logic-based Benders decomposition.
